# caml query to fetch selected fields from list

Tags: caml-query

I am having a list with 40 columns and need to fetch only 10 fields in a batch of 4. how to achieve this. Can someone provide me caml query. I prepared below caml to fetch 2 columns please let me know if this is correct and what addition i have to do. Thanks.

```
query.Viewfields= "<FieldRef name='column1'/><FieldRef name='column2'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi regarding to caml query for viewfields you can use below

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
           query.Query = string.Concat(
                          "<Where><Eq>",
                             "<FieldRef Name='Status'/>",
                             "<Value Type='CHOICE'>Not Started</Value>",
                          "</Eq></Where>",
                          "<OrderBy>",
                             "<FieldRef Name='DueDate' Ascending='TRUE' />",
                             "<FieldRef Name=’Priority’ Ascending='TRUE' />", 
                          "</OrderBy>");                    

           query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                               "<FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />",
                               "<FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' />",
                               "<FieldRef Name='DueDate' />",
                               "<FieldRef Name='Priority' />");

           query.ViewFieldsOnly = true; // Fetch only the data that we need.
```

[Here is reference to it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try this it works.

```
 var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Test</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
<FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
               <FieldRef Name='Modified' /> \
             <FieldRef Name='lastname' /> \
             <FieldRef Name='Firstname' /> \
             <FieldRef Name='Phone' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
  </viewFields> \
  <query> \
   <Query> \
<Where> \
<Or> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
     <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
</Contains> \
<Or> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='lastname' /> \
     <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
</Contains> \
<Or> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='Firstname' /> \
     <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
  </Contains> \
           <Contains> \
           <FieldRef Name='Phone' /> \
              <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
              </Contains> \
        </Or> \
     </Or> \
  </Or> \
  </Where> \
</Query> \
  </query> \
   </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
               query.Query = string.Concat(
                              "<Where><Eq>",
                                 "<FieldRef Name='col1'/>",
                                 "<Value Type='CHOICE'>Not Started</Value>",
                              "</Eq></Where>",
                              "<OrderBy>",
                                 "<FieldRef Name='col2' Ascending='TRUE' />",
                                 "<FieldRef Name=’col3’ Ascending='TRUE' />", 
                              "</OrderBy>");                    

               query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                                   "<FieldRef Name='col1' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='col2' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='col3' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='col4' />");

               query.ViewFieldsOnly = true; // Fetch only the data that we need.
```

Need to update ViewFieldsOnly to true.